# TopoJSON coordinates are off with actual coordinate using Leaflet

Tags: qgis, leaflet, geojson, topojson

I have this [TopoJSON file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/popoy2k/MandaLightMap/master/Choropleth/NCR/Mandaluyong/MandaTopo.json) that I have been working on quite sometime now. and recently I tried plotting it using Leaflet but the polygons are off with the actual area it surrounds. Here's the image.

[image]

Is there a way to adjust the polygons with their actual position within the map? I have a shapefile of it, can I do it with QGIS? Or there's a third-party app that I can use to adjust it?

Comment: the coordinates in the MandaTopo.json file are rounded [30, -33] they need to be 6 decimal places [30.xxxxxx, -33.xxxxxx] to prevent this issue

Comment: @Mapperz MandaTopo.json is a raw TopoJSON file and those rounded numbers are "arcs" but then later converted within the app using topojson.features() that result in coordinates. it does have decimal point up to 8 decimal places.

Comment: I actually have done it, it is quite pragmatic to what have I initial thought, I just play around with the coordinates.